# How do I add extra space between clusters?

Tags: graphviz

For nodes, there is `nodesep` which increases space between nodes.  Is there such an attribute for `subgraph cluster`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing distance between subgraphs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518389/increasing-distance-between-subgraphs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already tried to do this before. According to this link http://lists.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-devel/2009/000947.html, it seems that there is no current solution to the problem.

However, a little "hack" consists in surrounding your cluster with a chosen number of invisible clusters. In fact, the clusters have a small margin that can't be altered, but nesting them and hiding the border simulates a custom margin.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible hack if you're not using `rank` as an attribute, set `rank=same` within each cluster and then add a `ranksep=K`, where `K` is some factor you want to separate by.  Worked nicely for me.

Answer (score 1):

I set the `margin` option within each cluster. Though this does not separate the clusters, it add space between the nearest nodes, which may be sufficient for you, especially if you are using `style=invis`.