# Increasing distance between subgraphs

Tags: graph, graphviz

I have the following code:

```
digraph g {
graph [rankdir="LR" ,compound="true" ];
    subgraph cluster0 {
        graph [label="Ready\n\nAllowed Purchaser Operations:\noperation1,operation2\n\nAllowed Supplier Operations:\noperation1,operation3"  ];
        1 [ shape="none" ,fontcolor="white"  ];
    };
    subgraph cluster2 {
        graph [label="Paused\n\nAllowed Purchaser Operations:\noperation1,operation3\n\nAllowed Supplier Operations:\noperation2,operation3" ];
        3 [ shape="none" ,fontcolor="white"  ];
    };
    subgraph cluster4 {
        graph [label="Completed\n\nAllowed Purchaser Operations:\noperation4\n\nAllowed Supplier Operations:\noperation4" ];
        5 [ shape="none" ,fontcolor="white"  ];
    };
    1 -> 3 [ ltail="cluster0" ,lhead="cluster2" ,comment="6"  ];
    1 -> 5 [ ltail="cluster0" ,lhead="cluster4" ,comment="7"  ];
    3 -> 1 [ ltail="cluster2" ,lhead="cluster0" ,comment="8"  ];
    3 -> 5 [ ltail="cluster2" ,lhead="cluster4" ,comment="9"  ];
}
```

[image]

I want to increase the distance between the subgraphs. I've tried using `len`, `margin`, `pad`, but the syntax I've tried doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think what you are looking for (as [Emden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2348178/emden) points out) are indeed the [nodesep](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:nodesep) and [ranksep](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:ranksep) attributes.

```
graph [nodesep=6, ranksep=4];
```

The result would be:

[image]

Comment: it is late comment. But i have a query. Adding nodesep and ranksep will solve above solution. which is a great suggestion. But, other part of the graph will also expand. I just want to increase the distance between 2 clusters. Rest everything should remain same. Is it even possible?

Comment: @Vishwadeep Better open a new question for that ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Clusters are derived objects; their layout depends solely on the nodes contained in them. Thus, to alter the cluster spacing, you need to alter the node spacing. Try setting the ranksep and nodesep attributes to larger values.

Comment: Making ranksep gives me space vertically, but not horizontally. Highering nodesep  doesn`t work.

Comment: Works fine here - adding `nodesep=6;ranksep=4;` increases cleary the distances between the nodes.